# Pandas and scikit-learn - train_test_split dimensions of X, y

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, svm

I have a pandas datafrane with the following info:

> RangeIndex: 920 entries, 0 to 919  Data columns (total 41 columns)

```
X = df[df.columns[:-1]]
Y = df['my_Target']   
train_X,train_y,test_X, test_y =train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.33,shuffle = True, random_state=45)
```

The last column is the target, and the rest is the data. 
The shape is the following:

```
print(train_X.shape,train_y.shape,test_X.shape, test_y.shape)
```

> (616, 40) (304, 40) (616,) (304,)

However when I train a model:

```
model=svm.SVC(kernel='linear',C=0.1,gamma=0.1)
model.fit(train_X,train_Y)
prediction2=model.predict(test_X)
print('Accuracy for linear SVM is',metrics.accuracy_score(prediction2,test_Y))
```

it gives the following error:

> model.fit(train_X,train_Y)
>
> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of
>   samples: [616, 2]

Anyone got a hint about what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variables are in the wrong order:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
...     X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

[Per docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)
X_train then X_test then y_train and then y_test

You have:

train_X,train_y,test_X, test_y